# Convert Object to JSON File then to Bytes to save to an Storage and then back to Object

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3

Suppose I have the class Student which only has name and age attributes.

```
public class Student {
     private String studentName;
     private Integer age;
}
```

I want to convert this Student objects to JSON files (I think I can do this with Jackson mapper)

Then I need to store this .json file to an storage, so I have the method save(String key, byte[] resource) which saves any kind of file to the storage (.zip, .txt, etc.).

So I was wondering if I can do this like so:

1. Write value as String with jackson (Student to json)
2. Get the bytes of this String
3. Save to the Storage with save(studentName, bytes)

**Back to Student object:**

Then when I search an student from the storage I would need to convert back to String like so:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
String string = new String(studentBytes, charset);
```

Then String back to Student with Jackson mapper

Is this a good approach (I think not because the idea is that those bytes are actually a .json file, but are bytes of a java String object)? I am a little confused because the "file bytes" that I am saving are from a String object with this approach, but I can not find how to convert the Student object to a ".json file", can not figure out how to save .json file (which I do not need to save in disk because I only need the bytes to save to the cloud storage), how would I write an Object to an "in memory .json file" or maybe is not to see it as a file, just as bytes right? Please point in the right direction, like how to directly write the object to a json file and then store this file bytes?

Comment: FYI this is called serialization (and deserialization). Use [ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the info, the problem is how to take that json that I can obtain with the mapper to a .json file? I was thinking about this (to have "in memory json file") https://kodejava.org/how-to-read-and-write-java-object-to-json-file/ and then get the bytes of this file like so: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-file-into-an-array-of-bytes/ but I think it is too much

Comment: Use `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(student)` to serialize the student to a string and then use the AWS SDK to [put](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#putObject(software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest,java.nio.file.Path)) that [string](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/sync/RequestBody.html#fromString(java.lang.String)) to an object in S3. No need for an intermediate local file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is how you want to do it if you want to save json to a file to upload to S3. Jackson has a native json data structure (I think it's called `JsonNode`) but you don't want to save that to a file. Just save the json string to a text file.

To convert `Student` object to String:

```
Student student = new Student("Joe", 25);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json_string = mapper.writeValueAsString(student);
```

You can save this string to a text file and upload to S3.
When you want to get the `Student` object back:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Student student = mapper.readValue(new File("student.json"), Student.class);
```

Note that there is nothing special about a "json file". It's just a text file with the `.json` extention. It contains text data that happens to be in the Json format. You can save `json_string` to a file like this:

```
Path path = Paths.get("student.json");
byte[] strToBytes = json_string.getBytes();
Files.write(path, strToBytes);
```

(Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks, the part I am struggling is where you point "save this string to a text file", this part im missing on how to do it properly

Comment: You save the string to a text file using any way you like, nothing special about it. Json is a text data format. Here is a bunch of ways you can do it: https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file. I updated my answer to include one of the ways.

Comment: Im not sure if the read it back part will work, in my case, because remember that the file that comes from the storage is in the form of a byte[], how could I read them properly to get the "contents" (String object that is inside those bytes)

Comment: You already have the answer in your question: `String string = new String(studentBytes, charset);`